# Correct use of a colon in a list

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I am trying to express the contributions of members of a group in sentence. For instance, person A helped with x, person B helped with Y, and so on.

Is the use of the colon in the following sentence correct?

> The contributions of other members were: person A helped with x; person B helped with y; and person C helped with z.

Furthermore, could this be expressed as a list of dotpoints. An example is below.

The contributions of other members were:

- person A helped with x;
- person B helped with y; and
- person C helped with z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's common style that if a colon is used within a single sentence, what comes before the colon should form a complete sentence on its own.

Following that style guidance, the original sentence in the question should be rephrased slightly if the colon is to be kept:

> The other members made contributions: person A helped with x, person B helped with y, and person C helped with z.

Note that I also replaced the semicolons with commas, since that's the more common style choice in this particular construction.

---

At least with its *inline* use, the reason that what comes before a colon should be a complete sentences is that, if it isn't, the colon shouldn't be used at all.

From [*The Chicago Manual of Style*, 6.67](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch06/psec067.html) [paywall]:

> Many writers assume—wrongly—that a colon is always needed before a series or a list. In fact, if a colon intervenes in what would otherwise constitute a grammatical sentence … there is a good chance it is being used inappropriately. A colon, for example, should *not* be used before a series that serves as the object of a verb. When in doubt, apply this test: to merit a colon, the words that introduce a series or list must themselves constitute a grammatically complete sentence.
>
> The menagerie included cats, pigeons, newts, and deer ticks.
>             *not*
>       The menagerie included: cats, pigeons, newts, and deer ticks.

Taking the example sentence in the question, the inline version of it could also be written without the colon, also if it were rephrased slightly:

> The contributions of the other members were person A helping with x, person B helping with y, and person C helping with z.

---

Style guidance for a vertical list is more relaxed—and therefore much more open to subjective interpretation. You can make it the same sentence with the same punctuation, simply separated vertically, or you can introduce a series of individual phrases, clauses, or complete sentences.

Note, too, that if it's the same sentence with the same punctuation, that means a vertical list does not need to have its introductory sentence end with a colon.

So, maintaining the punctuation, the above two *inline* variations of the original sentence would become the following two vertical lists:

> The other members made contributions:
>
> - person A helped with x,
> - person B helped with y,
> - and person C helped with z.

> The contributions of the other members were
>
> - person A helping with x,
> - person B helping with y,
> - and person C helping with z.

But since guidance with vertical lists is more relaxed, the punctuation doesn't need to be maintained. At least in the first version where a complete sentence followed by colon is used to introduce the list, the list items could also each start with a capital letter and end with a period, start with a capital letter and end without punctuation, or start with a lowercase letter and end without punctuation.